# Magento which file have code of navigation menu bar?

Tags: php, magento

i want to edit the magento navigation menu bar code but i don't know that the which file have a menu bar code please help how can edit that file and change please help

```
i want to edit menu magento provide menu like
<ul>
    <li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>Abouty Us</a></li>

</ul>

i want to edit it like

<ul>
    <li><img src=''/><a href=''>Home</a></li>
    <li><img src=''/><a href=''>Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><img src=''/><a href=''>Abouty Us</a></li>

</ul>
```

i want to add image into menu and create advance menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hello friends you can also see the navigation menu bar into the navigation.php file

\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\navigation.php

that file have a navigation menu bar code

Comment: One should not make changes core files. You will not be able to make transfer your theme.

Comment: editing this file will make the site no longer upgrade-safe

Answer (score 13):

You should override the _getHtml() method in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu class.

Here are the steps:

1. create your app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu/Custom.php
2. put inside `class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Custom extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`
3. copy the _getHtml() method from app/code/code/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php and customize it as needed
4. edit your app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/layout/page.xml and replace `<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>` with `<block type="page/html_topmenu_custom" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>`
5. profit!

Answer (score 3):

```
app\design\frontend\default\yourtheme\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml
```

Comment: you specify file i don't have that file app\design\frontend\default\theme394\template\page\html on that path

Comment: thank you for quickly replay. i want to show image into menu how to do that please help

Comment: Copy it from -  app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml - and put in your theme

Comment: that file have that code i can't change it. i add costume image into menu                                                                   <?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

Comment: Please explain, how to do you want to add image. Its <ul><li></li></ul> in menu.

Comment: please again check my question and help

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Magento, this post may be out of date, so I will update. It looks like Magento made a change for this very reason to allow the customizing of that nav html.

If you look at line 80, in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu

```
    if ($renderer = $this->getChild('catalog.topnav.renderer')) {
        $renderer->setMenuTree($this->_menu)->setChildrenWrapClass($childrenWrapClass);
        $html = $renderer->toHtml();
    } else {
        $html = $this->_getHtml($this->_menu, $childrenWrapClass);
    }
```

It checks to see if a render block is defined, and if not then uses a deprecated method of building the nav html

```
/**
     * Recursively generates top menu html from data that is specified in $menuTree
     *
     * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @return string
     * @deprecated since 1.8.2.0 use child block catalog.topnav.renderer instead
     */
    protected function _getHtml(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass)
```

Try this block statement in the local.xml of your theme.

```
<default>
    <reference name="catalog.topnav">
        <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then you can pull down the template page/html/topmenu/render.phtml from the rwd theme into your own theme and make customizations without having to rewrite the block.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, replace this

```
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . $page['identifier']; ?>"><?php      echo $page['title']; ?></a>
</li>
```

BY

```
 <li><img src=''/>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . $page['identifier']; ?>"><?php      echo $page['title']; ?></a>
</li>
```

OK here is new code, replace the whole page code with this

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
 <?php if($_menu): ?>

 <?php $identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() ?>

 <?php $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()-     >addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());?>
 <?php  $collection->getSelect()
->where('is_active = 1'); ?>
<ul class="main-menu cf">
 <?php foreach ($collection as $page): ?>
<?php $PageData = $page->getData(); ?>

 <?php //make the current page active?>
<?php if($identifier == $PageData['identifier'] && $identifier != 'no-route'){ $c = 'class="active"';}else{ $c = '';}?>
<?php if($PageData['identifier']!='no-route' && $PageData['identifier']!='enable-cookies' && $PageData['identifier']!='home2') { ?>
 <li><img src=''/>
 <a <?php echo $c;?> href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . $page['identifier']; ?>"><?php       echo $page['title']; ?></a>
 </li>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
```

style it according to yours need. By replacing classes

Comment: please say me that file name which file code is replace please

Comment: in topmenu.phtml file have only that line code <?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

Comment: after replace that code then the output is blank please help and thank's to help me dear thank you so much